# Expected Value Definition

Tags: probability, expected-value

I believe my Macroeconomics professor is making (repeatedly) a notational abuse when writing the expected value of a random variable. He wrote the following: $$ \mathbb{E}(X) = \int x\hspace{0.1cm} dF(x)dx  $$

I believe he meant $$ \mathbb{E}(X) = \int x\hspace{0.1cm} f(x)dx $$ or $$ \mathbb{E}(X) = \int x\hspace{0.1cm} dF(x)$$.

Are these last two definitions equivalent? Is the first one wrong?

Thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration for definitions and examples of correct notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first expression looks like a typo to me. I'd ask a professor to explain it. Your equations are correct.

The last expression is used a lot in Microeconomics and Game theory, see [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT14_123S10_notes05.pdf) for example.

Comment: Congrats on 10k rep!